# D3.js zoom with Ordinal axis not working - Issue with setup of scale in zoom behavior?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scaling, zooming, ordinal

I am trying to create a simple zoom-able chart with a time scaled x-axis and an ordinal y-axis (an array of strings). The chart works fine with a real-valued y-axis, but when I use the ordinal y-axis I get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I've spent many hours at this and have narrowed the issue down, but just can't see the solution. I wonder if a D3 expert would kindly help me see the light.

For the expert reader, the exception occurs in the d3.v3.js rescale function at line 1344.

```
function rescale() {
      if (x1) x1.domain(x0.range().map(function(x) {
        return (x - view.x) / view.k;
      }).map(x0.invert));
      if (y1) y1.domain(y0.range().map(function(y) {
        return (y - view.y) / view.k;
      }).map(y0.invert));
    };
```

because y0 is undefined in the .map(y0.invert) line.

The culprit in my code appears to be the way I set up my ordinal scale function and use it in the zoom event handler. Here is my y-axis ordinal scale the axis set up and the zoom function snippets.

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(ordinals)
        .rangePoints([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient('left')
        .tickPadding(8);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

The error occurs before the zoom behavior calls my "zoomed" function.

In the zoom function, if I comment out the

```
.y(y)
```

the chart zooms correctly for x-axis, but of course the y-axis does not scale, since I am not giving the zoom behavior my ordinal scale, y. I'm not sure what I need to do to correct this. Can anyone kindly help?

I have included my full JavaScript below. Many big thanks in advance to anyone who can help me see the error of my ways!

```
var data = [
        { "date": "2012-03-20", "total": 3, "initiative": 0 },
        { "date": "2012-03-21", "total": 8, "initiative": 0 },
        { "date": "2012-03-22", "total": 2, "initiative": 1 },
        { "date": "2012-03-23", "total": 10, "initiative": 1 },
        { "date": "2012-03-24", "total": 3, "initiative": 2 },
        { "date": "2012-03-25", "total": 20, "initiative": 2 }
    ];

    var ordinals = ["a", "b", "c"];

    var margin = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40 },
        width = 600,
        height = 500;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
        .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(ordinals)
        .rangePoints([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(8);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient('left')
        .tickPadding(8);

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.bottom + ')')
        .call(zoom);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + (height - margin.top) + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.bottom + ')')
        .call(yAxis);

    map = svg.selectAll('.chart')
        .data(data)
        .enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function (d) { return x(new Date(d.date)) + margin.left; })
        .attr('y', function (d) { return y(ordinals[d.initiative]) + margin.bottom; })
        .attr('width', 50)
        .attr('height', 25);

    var clip = map.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", "clip-rect")
        .attr('stroke', 'red')
        .attr("width", width - margin.right - margin.left)
        .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.bottom + ')');

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoom);

    function zoomed() {

        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        map.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        map.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can zoom/pan on an ordinal axis.

One work around is that you make a linear scale and make it look like an ordinal scale.

Define your ordinals like this:

```
var ordinals = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Instead of ordinal scale make a linear scale:

```
var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, ordinals.length])
  .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);
```

Next when you make the yscale make use of the tick format to return the label of your choice.

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yscale)
  .orient('left')
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return ordinals[d];//now for 0 it will return 'a' for 1 b and so on...
  })
  .tickPadding(8);
```

Make your zoom to use the new y scale like this:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(yscale)
  .scaleExtent([1, 20])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Hide all ticks without label

```
var hideTicksWithoutLabel = function() {
  //hide ticks without label
  svg.selectAll(".y .tick")[0].forEach(function(g) {
    if (d3.select(g).select("text").text() == "") {
      d3.select(g).style("display", "none");
    } else {
      d3.select(g).style("display", "");
    }
  })
}
```

Now call this function after zoom.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/noq95b2w/1/)

Comment: That's great solution! Thank you very much.